# hibernate query caching not working if the data is empty in database

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

I am using Hibernate with L2 cache mechanism. I struck at one case where if the data is empty in the database table, L2 cache is not working and every time the call go to database as it is not found in L2 cache. Is is behaviour or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's behavior of cache. Even if you have data in database, call will go to database if data is not found in L2 cache. Nothing wrong with it.

> If requested data is contained in the cache (cache hit), this request can be served by simply reading the cache, which is comparatively faster. Otherwise (cache miss), the data has to be recomputed or fetched from its original storage location, which is comparatively slower.

Check [Cache on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)). First para itself will make it clear.